# What is the Debian equivalent for /etc/bashrc?

Tags: bash, debian, rhel

What is the Debian equivalent for `/etc/bashrc` (like on Red Hat)?

Answer (score 10):

The Debian manpage for Bash says

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist.

So the answer you seek seems to be `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

[Bash's own documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) only mentions `~/.bashrc`, but having a system-wide `bashrc` is [configurable at compile time](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/config-top.h?id=d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb#n93) and Debian has patched the man page to reflect that it's in use.

Comment: [It is configurable](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/config-top.h?id=d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb#n93).

Comment: `/etc/bash.bashrc` on Debian is completely different from `/etc/bashrc` on RHEL. The Debian's bash is modified with distro-specific patches (including the docs) to source `/etc/bash.bashrc` before anything else. On RHEL, `/etc/bashrc` is simply sourced by hand from the users' `~/.bashrc`, which means that they can bypass it.

Comment: ref. [deb-bash-config.diff](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~doko/+junk/pkg-bash-debian/view/head:/patches/deb-bash-config.diff#L31) and [man-bashrc.diff](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~doko/+junk/pkg-bash-debian/view/head:/patches/man-bashrc.diff#L33)

Comment: And the man diff is buggy: after three iterations, the got bored or `/etc/bash.bashrc` and fell back to `~/.bashrc` (line 52).

Comment: @JdeBP, funny that Bash's own documentation doesn't even mention it then.

Comment: There's a difference between a software package being *source*-configurable (eg. different defines could be used to customize it when *building* it -- as it's the case here with `SYS_BASHRC`) and being simply "configurable" at run-time (with eg env vars or /etc/files -- which is NOT the case here). Most software packages don't document all possible source configurations in their manpages. As already mentioned, Debian's configuration is a [source patch](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~doko/+junk/pkg-bash-debian/view/head:/patches/deb-bash-config.diff#L31).

Comment: @mosvy, it doesn't really matter it's a patch and not a `-D` or such in the build files. That first comment of yours made it seem like the whole feature was patched in by Debian, which it doesn't appear to be. The implementation is there in the original source, just disabled.

Comment: The whole feature was patched in by Debian. Look at that `config.h` file: if you change things there, you will get something that doesn't match the documented behaviour. Those "configurations" are not really user-serviceable. And then my main point stands: RHEL doesn't use that source tweak, RHEL's `/etc/bashrc` is NOT similar to Debian's `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: And I cannot check now, but I'm not sure if those `config.h` defines could be overridden by a `-D` flag.

Comment: @mosvy, what? That diff you linked shows just a define being uncommented. There's `#ifdef SYS_BASHRC [...] maybe_execute_file (SYS_BASHRC, 1);` in shell.c in the original Bash sources I have here. The _feature itself is there_ in the original source, it's just `ifdef''d out. Granted, it wouldn't be many lines to add if it wasn't, but still. The documentation is of course a different matter. Sure, that configuration hardly serviceable by the end-user of the shell, but in the context of the user building the software, it's quite configurable. At least if you know it's there...

Comment: A source patch is a source patch, no matter how trivial it may look. IIRC some years ago they broke openssh in Debian by the maintainer "cleaning up" the upstream code or something like that. But it was not my intention to start a pointless "discussion"; I've given the links so any reader can make up her or his own mind. Hopefully some mod doesn't remove them as "noise" or "no longer necessary".

Comment: @mosvy, a build-time config option is a build-time config option, no matter if it's a `#define` in some `config.h`, a `-D` in a makefile or `--enable-xxx` in `configure`.

Comment: (@mosvy, and since we're talking about messages being perceived as noise, what ever does OpenSSH have to do with this)

Comment: You didn't tell me: could you override that define with `./configure --enable-xxx` or with a `-D` in Makefile? Could they have used that instead of patching the source in Debian? Sorry about OpenSSH, it was a typo. It was about OpenSS**L**: since we were talking about distro-specific patches in Debian and deceptively trivial source changes (as the one implementing the `/etc/bash.bashrc`), I remembered a [catastrophic example](https://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571) of a Debian maintainer overriding the upstream via distro-specific patches that looked completely harmless.

Comment: @mosvy, I didn't look at the configure script, I didn't test with a `-D`, but I _assume_ it would work the same as any define (the default `config-top.h` doesn't disable the define). But I don't really care, like I said, a build-time config option is a build-time config option, regardless of how it's implemented.

Comment: @mosvy, as for OpenSSL, again, how is that relevant here? Patching the actual code is a bit different from just enabling an option already exists there, in a file called "config", with a comment saying what it does (and not, e.g. saying "don't use this, it's broken"). You also forgot that the OpenSSL code that triggered that particular case relied on undefined behaviour, and was of questionable usefulness to begin with...

Comment: If you don't undefine a define, you'll get a warning/error: `cc -Werror -E -xc - <<<'#define FOO bar' -D FOO=quux`. You cannot override a source define like that. But as I said, let's cut it here. I absolutely don't understand your resistance to clarify your answer, but as in other cases like that, there may be other factors at play -- that I don't care to know about.

Comment: @mosvy, the original line I can see in the Bash source is `/* #define SYS_BASHRC "/etc/bash.bashrc" */` (it's in a comment). `-D SYS_BASHRC=blah` shouldn't clash with that, as far as I understand.

Comment: @mosvy, I clarified that answer [4 hours ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/570904/revisions) to say that it's a compile-time configuration. I don't see other relevant points here. But as always, you're free to post your own answer instead of insisting on your views in comments.

Comment: @mosvy, as for the fact that RHEL's `/etc/bashrc` is sourced from files in `~`, and in Debian `/etc/bash.bashrc` is read by the shell directly, I honestly don't think that's particularly relevant for most users. Sure, it's a curious point, and makes a difference if one wants to disable the system-level file, but I hardly see it as a decisive factor regarding the question at hand. It's good if you to point the difference out, however, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 8):

Does this help you? In my debian buster:

```
find /etc -type f -name "*bashrc*" 2> /dev/null
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: Yes this does, when I edited /etc/bash.bashrc I was able to set aliases systemwide. Thanks!

Comment: fwiw, `/etc/bash.bashrc` on Debian is not exactly similar to `/etc/bashrc` on RHEL: the users cannot bypass it on Debian. See the comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570898/what-is-the-debian-equivalent-for-etc-bashrc/570904#comment1062035_570904)