# Changes to PS1 in bash.bashrc are not reflected on the terminal's prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

I want the prompt of all users to output date and time, and in file `/etc/bash.bashrc` I set:

```
PS1='\D{%Y%m%d}-\t~\u@\h \$ '
```

I reboot the system, and after I open a terminal, I see that my prompt has not changed.

What file should I adjust to have the prompt of all users set as I defined above?

Comment: Of course you realize that any user own personal setting in whatever .bashrc* of their home directory will override your global setting.

Comment: At least in Ubuntu, every user has `.bashrc` which sets `PS1` by default. See `/etc/skel/.bashrc` for an example.

Answer (score 3):

On my system the PS1 is overwritten again by the bashrc-script in the home folder,
in `~/.bashrc`. Try adding it to this file. By the way, the order in which those and other init files are evaluated is described in the man page in the sections `FILES` and `INVOCATION`.

Edit: you can debug the startup process of bash to check whether my diagnosis is correct by running `bash -x`.

To solve it being shown to all users, you can only edit the per-user config in the skeleton dir `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, then your changes to `PS1` will be available to newly created users. This will not affect already created users, which have the PS1-overwriting `.bashrc`. For those you have to edit (or perhaps ask those users to edit) the per-user configs in `~user/.bashrc.`, adding your change or deleting the PS1-overwriting command.

Comment: Does your Bash manual also mention `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

Comment: Yes, certainly. Check `man bash`

Comment: Are you on Debian (or a derivative)? I think Debian adds a mention to `bash.bashrc`, which instead does not appear in most of the other manuals, e.g. that from [The Linux man-pages Project](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), the [upstream documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) itself (both Texinfo an man) and that from other distributions (I am on Arch, no mention of that file despite it being used).

Comment: Again, yes, I use debian (or ubuntu at work). I am very surprised to hear that my manpage seems to have been patched by the distro. This info should really be a basic part of the upstream bash documentation!

Comment: The use of `/etc/bash.bashrc` depends on a compilation option, it is not always-on. I guess it should be up to the distributions to document it when appropriate, and probably Debian stands out positively in this respect. ([This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570904/315749) and its comments have more details and a bit of... debate on the subject).